# Android store json data from php in String[]

Tags: php, android, arrays, json, string

I have a JSON like `[{"id":"67","Title":"1852","CustomLabel":"66479"}, {"id":"68","Title":"1859","CustomLabel":"5478"}...]`

Now I would store "Title"s in a String[] in order to pass it to an `AutoCompleteTextView` but I'm a newbie and I don't know how.

Could anyone help me? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your problem now?? dont you know how to implement autocomplete??

Comment: Google will helps you. SO is just for solution if you have problem not for `How to implement?`

Comment: My fault, don't know how to store "Title" in a String[].
Already implemented autocomplete textview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
 //You have jsonArray so Store it in jsonArray Object.
 int len = jsonArray.length();

 String[] titles = new String[len];

 for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
     final JSONObject e = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
     titles[i] =e.getString("Title");
 }
```

and set **Adapter** to **AutoCompleteTextView** like:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, titles);
 AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
            findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
 textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
//  [{"id":"67","Title":"1852","CustomLabel":"66479"}, {"id":"68","Title":"1859","CustomLabel":"5478"}]
    public void s()
    {
        ArrayList<String> titleArr = new ArrayList<String>();
        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject o = arr.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = o.optString("id");
            String title = o.optString("Title");
            String customLabel = o.optString("CustomLabel");
            titleArr.add(title);
        }
    }
```